# When updating multiple MySQL tables in one query, is assignment order always guaranteed?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

Consider the example in which tables A and B are updated in one query such that A.Column1 is set to B.Column2 (value "DEF") and then B.Column2 is set to value "XYZ." Is the assignment order always guaranteed so that A.Column1's value is "DEF" and not "XYZ"?

SQL example:

```
UPDATE TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.Column0 = a.Column0
SET
    a.Column1 = b.Column2, -- Original value: "DEF"
    b.Column2 = 'XYZ'
WHERE a.Column0 = 123;

SELECT Column1 FROM TableA WHERE Column0 = 123; -- DEF or XYZ?
```

Comment: In MySQL, you may need a before update trigger to make this behavior reliable in a multi-table join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting [the documentation on `UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) is pretty clear on this:

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result is that col1 and col2 have the same value. *This behavior differs from standard SQL.*

So surprisingly, yes, order does matter and is respected. This seems to be a quirky MySQL thing, though, so I wouldn't lean too heavily on it as switching to another RDBMS would cause considerable confusion when it stops working.

Comment: Looking at the documentation a little further, I came across this: `Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.` Does this change the correctness of this answer?

Comment: I've always been extremely cautious when making expectations on execution order like this for reasons like that. MySQL's quirky behaviour is often subtly conditional making it unpredictable. As always, test, test, and test again to be sure you got it right.